# Golang create json array

Tags: json, go

I try to create json array

```
type Data struct {
Veggies Vegetables
array   array } type array map[string] []int
func main(){
vegetables := Vegetables{}
vegetables["Carrots"] = 21
n:= array{}
n  ["array"]= [] int {1, 1 ,1}
d := Data{ vegetables,n}

json.MarshalIndent(d, "", " ")}
```

please explain why not see the array?

Comment: Output : {
 "Veggies": {
  "Carrots": 21
 }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above doesn't compile, but also has a few problems with the types. I'd avoid names like Array which could be confused for language keywords, and forgo the custom types. Maybe something simpler like this?

https://play.golang.org/p/OBw4gI2Zkm

```
type Data struct {
    Veggies map[string]int
    Ints    []int
}
...
j, err := json.MarshalIndent(d, "", " ")
```

The docs for the json package are good, you need to read them.

https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal

For Go, this book is also great as an introduction to the language:

http://www.gopl.io/

Answer (score 0):

To use an Unmarshaller, the struct data members need to be exported. That is, they need to be capitalized, or the unmarshaller does not have access. Capitalize `Array` in your `Data` struct. `Veggies` is the only one unmarshaled because it's capitalized and therefore exported.